# Change the numerical sequence in filenames using bash/shell command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a group of files named in numerical sequence order from 1 to 1000,

s_nn_1.txt, s_nn_2.txt ..... s_nn_1000.txt .

I want to change the name of the file in a different sequence order as,

s_nn_1001.txt, s_nn_1002.txt .... s_nn_2000.txt .

I tried using two variables in 'for' loop but didn't work.

```
 for i in {1..1000}
do
for j in {1001..2000}
do
mv s_nn_"$i".txt s_nn_"$j".txt
done
done
```

Can you give any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have access to Perl's standalone `rename` or `prename` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain bash:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i)); do
    mv -i s_nn_$i.txt s_nn_$((i + 1000)).txt
done
```

Answer (score 2):

While not an issue for OP's example, overlapping filenames should be considered when deciding on the order to perform the `mv's`.

If OP were going from `{1..1000}` to `{500..1500}`, half the files will be lost (eg, `mv file1 file500` will overwrite the current `file500`, and later `mv file500 file1000` will actually be making a copy of the original `file1` and saving as `file1000`).

Generally speaking:

- if increasing the numeric values then process the files in reverse numeric order
- if decreasing the numeric values then process the files in (normal) numeric order

Applying this to OP's current code, and knowing the increase is `+1000`:

```
for i in {1000..1}
do
    mv s_nn_"$i".txt s_nn_"$((i+1000))".txt
done
```